# Open Json a Json field in SQL Server to table

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, open-json

I have a table in SQL Server where a row contains a Json column - something like this:

| ResponseText | RequestId |
| --- | --- |
| {"LosUnqCod":0,"LosMidId":23} | 96173722 |
| {"LosUnqCod":1,"LosMidId":5} | 96173721 |

I want to have a table in this shape:

| LosUnqCod | LosMidId | RequestId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23 | 96173722 |
| 1 | 5 | 96173721 |

how to open this json?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `OPENJSON` if you only have one JSON object (not an array) per SQL row, you can use `JSON_VALUE` instead:

```sql
SELECT        
    JSON_VALUE(a.responsetext, '$.LosUnqCod') LosUnqCod,
    JSON_VALUE(a.responsetext, '$.LosMidId') LosMidId,
    a.RequestId
FROM [dbo].[a];
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi every body I found my answer and want to share with anyone who has the same issue as I does

```
  SELECT        
    
        reqTbl.LosUnqCod ,
        a.RequestId
    
   FROM   [dbo].[a]  CROSS APPLY      
                     OPENJSON( dbo.a.responsetext) 
                     WITH (
                        LosUnqCod nvarchar(50)
                        ) AS reqTbl
```